# Win 7 + IE 11 First video plays but second and later videos won't play

Tags: javascript, html, video, internet-explorer-11

I've a list of video's in a page. The videos are fetched from Server via Rest API and are used in html as below. The first video plays well but later video's wont play. The resolution are same for all video. This works well in other browsers and platform.

```
<video width="645" height="425" id="myvideo" class ='video' controls controlsList="nodownload">
    <source id="source" src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

In my source tag, I've mentioned type="video/mp4"

In JS Side I do the below

```
$("#source")[0].src = <path-to-the-video>;
```

This works great on all browers and platform except for windows 7 and ie 11.
The error I get is

```
MEDIA12899: AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type.
```

I've checked over the net

1. to add the type="video/mp4" which is already there and does not solve the problem.
2. The video resolutions are correct because the same video works in the same IE and Window when played in a separate HTML file.

What am I missing?

Error Screen Shot
[image: Screenshot]

Same Video working in same browser when added to a html file

```
<video width="645" height="425" class="video" id="myvideo" style="display: inline-block;" controls="" controlslist="nodownload">
    <source id="source" src="http://hostname.com1/video2" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Screenshot
[image: s]

Comment: developer tools network tab - what mimetype are you receiving

Comment: application/octet-stream

Comment: Well there's your problem. Server

Comment: What should it be? The same thing works in first video and if I call the URL directly in IE11 also it works.

Comment: it should be a valid video mimetype

Comment: That's a valid type. The same API works for first video but not for second video. Seems some other issue.

Comment: that's not a valid *video* mimetype at all. As the error refers to mime type, and the mime type sent is not a valid video mime type, I propose you send the appropriate mime type and see if that fixes the issue